# Make a mutation call in angular (getting "Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/graphql: 400 Bad Request")

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo-server, mutation

Im new to both GraphQL and angular im trying to follow the documentation but not able to make a mutation.
Below is the ts file code

```
export const USER_SIGNUP = gql`
  mutation AddUser($userInput: UserInput) {
    addUser(userInput: $userInput) {
      id
      name
      email
      password
    }
  }
`;

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Apollo } from 'apollo-angular';
import { USER_SIGNUP } from 'src/app/graphql/user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-up',
  templateUrl: './sign-up.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-up.component.scss'],
})
export class SignUpComponent {

  constructor(private apollo: Apollo) {}

  userSignUp() {
    this.apollo
      .mutate({
        mutation: USER_SIGNUP,
        variables: {
          userInput: {
            name: 'YRT',
            email: 'RTRT',
            password: '1542',
          },
        },
      })
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          console.log(data);
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log(err.message);
        }
      );
  }
}
```

And below is the html file code

```
<div class="sign-up-main-container">
  <div>
    <app-auth-bg-component></app-auth-bg-component>
  </div>
  <form (ngSubmit)="userSignUp()" class="sign-up-form">
    <div>
      <label>Name</label>
      <div class="sign-up-input-cont">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name." />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Email</label>
      <div class="sign-up-input-cont">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email." />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Password</label>
      <div class="sign-up-input-cont">
        <input [type]="passwordType" placeholder="Enter your password." />
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Signup</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

The below is my nestjs code for user resolver where i have defined the mutation

```
import { Resolver, Query, Mutation, Args } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { User, UserInput } from './users.model';

@Resolver()
export class UserResolver {
  constructor(public userService: UserService) {}

  @Query(() => String)
  hello() {
    return 'hello';
  }

  @Mutation(() => User)
  addUser(@Args('userInput') userInput: UserInput) {
    return this.userService.addUser(userInput);
  }
}
```

I have followed the documentation but dont know why im getting this error ("Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/graphql: 400 Bad Request") please help me with this.

Below is the input type of userInput

```
@InputType()
export class UserInput {
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  id: string;

  @Field()
  name: string;

  @Field()
  password: string;

  @Field()
  email: string;
}
```

Comment: If anyone needs more details feel free to ask I can provide

Comment: Please include the definition of the `UserInput` input type from the server schema as well as the `addUser` mutation. A 400 is normally an invalid GraphQL query or mutation. I'm a bit suspicious of `email: 'RTRT'` unless email is defined to just be a `String`.

Comment: @MichelFloyd
Below is the input type of userInput. I have also updated my question Thankyou.

```
@InputType()
export class UserInput {
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  id: string;

  @Field()
  name: string;

  @Field()
  password: string;

  @Field()
  email: string;
}
```

Comment: Can you also include the definition of the `addUser` mutation from the schema?

Comment: @MichelFloyd Thanks for your help man, but I found the mistake. Don't know what is the importance of "!" here but added that and it worked, if you know why we had to use that please tell me. Thank you.

Comment: @MichelFloyd 
Having a problem regarding .env

I'm trying to use .env.local file and change the URI of Apollo client depending on the environment but it's not working.

It's only working when I hardcode the URI like below.

import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";

const CreateApolloClient = () => {
  return new ApolloClient({
    uri: `http://localhost:4000/graphql`,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });
};

export default CreateApolloClient;

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While defining the mutation i had to use the "!" mark like below.

```
export const USER_SIGNUP = gql`
  mutation AddUser($userInput: UserInput!) {
    addUser(userInput: $userInput) {
      id
      name
      email
      password
    }
  }
`;
```

Don't know what is the importance of "!" here but added that and it worked, if any of you know why we had to use that please tell me. Thank you.

Comment: What this is telling me is that your `AddUser` mutation is defined with `UserInput!` which means *non-nullable* - it has to be provided.

Comment: Okay got it .